# String.translate opposite

Tags: python, string

I am new to python and was wondering if there was an opposite of string.translate()
I want to pass my function a long string but be able to keep only the letters in the alphabet and filter out the rest ! (Note I will most likely need to extend the things I need to filter to commas and periods hence any pre built filter method will be helpful !)

UPDATE

I have a brute force version but this is highly undesirable

```
def filterFunction(text):
    text.split
    filteredtext=([elem for elem in text if elem.isalpha()==True or elem==","or elem=="."or elem==" "])
    print filteredtext
    return filteredtext
```

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: I have a brute force version but this is highly undesirable                             def filterFunction(text):
    text.split
    filteredtext=([elem for elem in text if elem.isalpha()==True or elem==","or elem=="."or elem==" "])
    print filteredtext
    return filteredtext

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexes for that.

```
import re
myString = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", "", myString)
```

In case you want to keep the white spaces too, just change the regex to:

```
myString = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z ]", "", myString)
```

Comment: Regex would be an option but I would want to extend this later to filter commas and periods

Comment: Do you mean filtering just commas and periods? That can be done with regexes too: `re.sub("[\.|,]", "", myString)`.

Comment: I meant in addition to the alphabet filter commas and periods.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly: you want to keep the alphabet, commas, and periods and remove everything else?

Comment: Yes so given a string $John_Blake  the function returns JohnBlake as it detects that $ and_ are not part of the alphabet or commas or periods

Comment: That should still be doable with a regex `re.sub("[^a-zA-Z|\.|,]", "", myString)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex as suggested in other answers or you can loop over characters yourself.

You can use `string.isalpha` method to check if a character is an alphabet

```
myString = filter(lambda char: char.isalpha(), myString)
```

Though in `python3` you need to it differently since filter returns an iterator

```
myString = ''.join(list(filter(lambda char: char.isalpha(), myString)))
```

or simple list comprehension

```
myString = ''.join([char for char in myString if char.isalpha()])
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose a solution using list comprehension.

```
"".join([i for i in s if i.isalpha()])

s = "Hello World"
"".join([i for i in s if i.isalpha()]) #HelloWorld
s = "1234532 32132"
"".join([i for i in s if i.isalpha()]) # ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple generator comprehension and str.join method:

```
tested_str = "s12jf#@GDVC2"
expected = "sjfGDVC"
result = ''.join(c for c in tested_str if c.isalpha())
assert result == expected
```

Comment: But this has to work for function which will receive multiple string parameters I can't hard code the expected all the time.